# RhinoMocks: can't test if a method has been called

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to test this very simple method:

```
 public IBus Bus { get; set; }

 public void SendData(OrderHeader order)
 {
     if (Bus == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("Bus");
     Bus.Publish<UpdateOrder>(msg =>
         {
             msg.EventId = Guid.NewGuid();
             msg.EventTime = DateTime.Now;
             msg.Order = order;
         });
 }
```

To test that Bus.Publish has been called, I tried 3 different approaches, and none of them work :/
Can anybody help me understand what's going on here? What am I doing wrong?

### First one, the AAA pattern with AssertWasCalled:

#### this is the one that I'd like most to make it work

```
[Fact]
public void SendData_PassingOrderHeader_PublishAnUpdateOrderMessage()
{
    var sender = new Sender();
    var myBusMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IBus>();
    sender.Bus = myBusMock;
    sender.SendData(new OrderHeader());
    myBusMock.AssertWasCalled(b => b.Publish<UpdateOrder>(Arg<UpdateOrder>.Is.Anything));            
}
```

Error:

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException
IBus.Publish<LVR.Communication.Bus.Order.Protocol.UpdateOrder>(anything); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

### Second one using stub and WhenCalled method:

```
[Fact]
public void SendData_PassingOrderHeader_PublishAnUpdateOrderMessage2()
{
    var sender = new Sender();
    var myBusMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IBus>();
    sender.Bus = myBusMock;
    bool iBusPublishHasBeenCalled = false;
    myBusMock.Stub(b => b.Publish<UpdateOrder>(Arg<UpdateOrder>.Is.Anything)).WhenCalled(invocation =>
        {
            iBusPublishHasBeenCalled = true;
        }
        );
    sender.SendData(new OrderHeader());
    Assert.True(iBusPublishHasBeenCalled);
}
```

Error:

```
Assert.True() Failure
```

### Third one, mocking with expectations and verification phase:

```
[Fact]
public void SendData_PassingOrderHeader_PublishAnUpdateOrderMessage3()
{
    var sender = new Sender();
    var myBusMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IBus>();
    sender.Bus = myBusMock;
    bool iBusPublishHasBeenCalled = false;
    myBusMock.Expect(b => b.Publish<UpdateOrder>(Arg<UpdateOrder>.Is.Anything));
    sender.SendData(new OrderHeader());
    myBusMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Error:

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException
IBus.Publish<LVR.Communication.Bus.Order.Protocol.UpdateOrder>(anything); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Publish` method takes a lambda (i.e. `Action` or `Func`) as an argument, not `UpdateOrder`. I've just implemented your first attempt, and after I've changed the `Arg` argument to correctly reflect the method signature it works.

As a side note: by custom, *mocks* are supposed to be verified for method calls, *stubs* shouldn't. A *stub* is something only to make the test compile and run without influence on the outcome. IIRC in Rhino mocks they made them (almost?) synonymous for convenience. That makes your first and third approaches seemingly the best ones.

Comment: The second apporaches was created just to understand the nature of the problem, so I knew it was the worst one. Given that I deleted from the first approach a useless line of code that stubs the method (it was a misprint), what about the first one? I'm using a mock to verify a behaviour (if a method will be called). Does it it look all right to you now? I don't really love the expect/verify flavor

Comment: @themarcuz Yeah, it looks all right. I also like it better, it's more readable, not cluttered with rhino setup-code that much.